# Div Layout Positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, layout

I'm trying to accomplish the following layout:

[image: Target Layout]

I want a centered Brain with four square links. The "Polaroids" one the left and the right should appear if you are hovering over the right part of the navigation button. So if you hover over the first like in the picture, the first polaroid left up corner should appear.

I tried the following div structure:

```css
.html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.title {
  font-family: lato;
}
.main-content {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #fefdf9;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.page {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.top-left {
  background-color: #fefdf9;
  width: 35%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  min-height: 1px;
}
.top-middle {
  background-color: #fefdf9;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.top-right {
  background-color: #fefdf9;
  width: 35%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  min-height: 1px;
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 8px;
}
.footer {
  background-color: #383838;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: auto;
}
.FooterText {
  FONT-SIZE: 26px;
  FONT-FAMILY: "Lato Bold";
  color: rgb(255, 79, 78);
}
.header {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  max-height: 60px;
}
.header-top {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  line-height: 0;
  font-family: "Lato Thin";
}
.header-bot {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4%;
  display: inline;
  font-family: "Lato Black";
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
.Left {
  width: 37%;
  min-height: 1px;
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.left > div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #555;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}
.Middle {
  width: 26%;
  float: left;
  margin: auto;
  height: 580px;
}
.Right {
  width: 37%;
  min-height: 1px;
  float: left;
}
#h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
}
#Willkommenstext {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: justify;
}
.News {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  padding-left: 20%
}
.News img {
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 100%;
  border-bottom: 45px solid #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #777;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #777;
}
.News p {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 60px;
  font: 400 18px/1'Lato', cursive;
  color: #888;
}
.Kontakt {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  padding-left: 25%;
  margin-top: -15%;
}
.Kontakt img {
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 100%;
  border-bottom: 45px solid #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #777;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #777;
}
.Kontakt p {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 60px;
  font: 400 18px/1'Lato', cursive;
  color: #888;
}
.Kalender {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  padding-left: 10%
}
.Kalender img {
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 100%;
  border-bottom: 45px solid #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #777;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #777;
}
.Kalender p {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 60px;
  font: 400 18px/1'Lato', cursive;
  color: #888;
}
.Anfahrt {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  margin-top: -15%;
}
.Anfahrt img {
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 100%;
  border-bottom: 45px solid #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #777;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #777;
}
.Anfahrt p {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 60px;
  font: 400 18px/1'Lato', cursive;
  color: #888;
}
.left1 {
  width: 10%;
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 1px;
}
.left2 {
  width: 10%;
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 1px;
}
body {
  background: #F1F1F1;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: small;
}
ul.square-menu {
  font-size: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Kavoon", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
ul.square-menu li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
}
ul.square-menu li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 80px 60px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 150%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
}
ul.square-menu li a.slink-x {
  background-image: url(../images/NavLeftUp.gif);
  background-repeat: no;
  background-size: 100%;
}
ul.square-menu li a.slink-y {
  background-image: url(../images/NavRightUp.gif);
  background-repeat: no;
  background-size: 100%;
}
ul.square-menu li a.slink-z {
  background-image: url(../images/NavLeftDown.gif);
  background-repeat: no;
  background-size: 100%;
}
ul.square-menu li a.slink-a {
  background-image: url(../images/NavRightDown.gif);
  background-repeat: no;
  background-size: 100%;
}
ul.square-menu li a:hover {
  font-size: 26px;
  a -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -o-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="page">

        <div class="top-left">
        </div>

        <div class="top-middle">
          <div class="header">

            <div class="header-top" style="display=" inline="">
              <h1>Test Header</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="header-bot">
              <h2>Test Underline</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="top-right">
        </div>

      </div>


      <div class="content">
        <div class="Left">

          <div class="News">
            <p>News</p>
            <img src="./images/news.jpg">
          </div>

          <div class="Kontakt">
            <p>News 2</p>
            <img src="./images/news.jpg">
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="Middle">

          <ul class="square-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="slink-x">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="slink-y">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="slink-z">News</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="slink-a">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <br style="clear:both;" />
          </ul>


          <table id="Willkommenstext" width="420" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vitae fringilla neque, a elementum ligula. Proin arcu velit, euismod a. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vitae fringilla neque, a elementum ligula.
                  Proin arcu velit, euismod a.</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

        <div class="Right">
          <div class="Kalender">
            <p>Kalender</p>
            <img src="./images/news.jpg">
          </div>

          <div class="Anfahrt">
            <p>Anfahrt</p>
            <img src="./images/news.jpg">
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="footer">

          <table width="50%" align="center">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>BildLogo</td>
                <td>Impressum</td>
                <td>About</td>
                <td>Kontakt</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

        </div>
      </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The result is this:

[image]

I am a ABSOLUTE Beginner and managed to get to this point, so i wont stop^^ As far as I understood I can not change the boxes visibility with css and hover because my divs are not nested.

I stumbled upon javascript and jquery for this, but this looks like kinda too complicated to get it working without learning the language.

Is there a way to change the div structure so i can hide the Polaroids with css?

I would be very thankful for a solution to this, I am kinda stuck since a few days. If there is no other way than java/jquery i would take that also :D

Thank you very much my friends! :)